# string match by tokens - concept check

Tags: c++, token, string-matching, extended-ascii

This question is for a concept check. I have a string 000.00-010.0.0.0 that I'd like to find the closest match to from the list {000.00-012.0.0.0 and 000.00-008.0.0.0} (include with the edit measure a numerical distance measure) I'd like to take '012', '010' and '008' as tokens and measure the distance between these.

The standard approach to string match will look for a change in each char position, sum the changes and return a distance. A modified distance will also measure the ASCII distance between the CHARS - G is farther from E than D.

To measure that '012' is to '010' as '008' is, requires bundling three chars into a token. Can this token be easily measured for edit distance and distance? The problem seems more complicated by the removal of delimiters in the tree database.

My proposed solution I want a reality check on is to convert '012', '010', and '008' into single CHAR ASCII symbols, say ), *, and +, measure the char distance and string edit distance, then on print convert back into '012', '010', and '008'.

Sample string: `MER99.C0.00M.14.006.00.060.350`

And, there are wildcards:

- `MER99.*.006.00.060.350`
- `MER99.C0.00M.??.006.00.060.350`

Since the strings are the same length (some need dummy char for length, '00M' is actually 'M') matching is with the Hamming distance.

I do not need help with the match algorithm, the Hamming distance approach, wildcards, or the dummy char, I added this for context to the question. Right now, I treat the token as separate char and get good results, but know they are not as exact as could be if handled as a token. The limiting factor is probably the inconsistency within the coding schema.  But, I'd like to have that as the limit and not my algorithm.

Comment: Why do you want to change '012', '010' and '008' to one char ? You could do what you said, sum each character difference (absolute value)... Ex: `'012' - '010' : 0 [for '0'] + 0 [for '1'] + 2 [for '2' and '0'] = 2`

Comment: `'032' - '020' : 0 [for '0'] + 1 [for '3' and '2'] + 2 [for '2' and '0'] != 3` it is 12 so `'+' less '*' = 12`

Comment: actually it is 12 * 1; 1 is for the edit and 12 is the distance between 'leafs'

Comment: I assume '012' is a 3-digit decimal number. You cannot change this number in a single char: the values will go from 0 to 999 which obviously does not fit in [0;255].

Comment: For 12: `100 * 0 [for '0' and '0'] + 10 * 1 [for '3' and '2'] + 1 * 2 [for '2' and '0']`

Comment: @Synxis - lucky, my set is only 8 to 135 and so it works for this case - I will check how general that is.

Comment: @Synxis, I found a case that goes to 235, so this is not a general solution. But, they are inefficient, they use 000.00 through sofar 235.00 but the '.00' never exceeds '07'. They could compact their structure through better use of the second token and then have no reason to ever exceed '099'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings contains alpha-numerical characters, ie base 36 number. Furthermore, these characters are grouped in 'tokens'. It cannot be stored in a `char`, but you can store it in an `int`.

Instead of storing ints in your tree, you can store a pair, where the char tells the type of the value:

- `0` for a numeric value
- `1` for `*`
- `2` for `xxxx?` (mask)
- etc...

Comment: why is it helpful to convert to the int equivalent? Also, the character separation is removed to allow for string matching. I guess they could be left there in the tree, there would be nodes for '.'

Comment: no need to write the code, I can write it. So you would build a tree of int and then compare those for a match? One problem, part of my structure is alphanumeric - I left that out to simplify the question. I am not reusing 'A' through 'Z' of the ASCII table. I could convert the letter char to some representative  int and use your approach.

Comment: I added an example string to the question

Comment: I've edited my answer. There are some things in your question that are a bit unclear: the tree (you just mentioned it), and the 'edit distance'. I hope I'm closer to what you want

Comment: no, I am still working on this. I can not explain it well enough, so thank you for your answer. Here is a wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: Interesting link! Thank you for your share ;). I understand better, now.